# При считывании из файла в буфер первые 6 байтов мусор

Tags: c, текстовые-файлы

При считывании из входного текстового файла в буфер первые шесть байт мусор
(e2 80 8b e2 80 8b). Как обойти этот случай? Возможно, это маркер кодировки, но он мешает дальнейшему форматированию текста.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
 
int main() {

    FILE *in_file  = fopen("./files/test.txt", "r"); // read only 
    FILE *out_file = fopen("./files/news.out", "w"); // write only 
           
    // test for files not existing. 
    if (in_file == NULL || out_file == NULL) 
    {   
        printf("Error! Could not open file\n"); 
        exit(-1); // must include stdlib.h 
    }    

    hexdump(in_file, out_file);

    fclose(in_file);
    fclose(out_file);

    return 0;
}

void hexdump(FILE *input, FILE *output) {
    unsigned char buffer[17];
    size_t len;
    int num = 0;

    fflush(input);
    fflush(output);

    while (!feof(input)){
        len = fread(buffer, sizeof(*buffer), 16, input);
        for (size_t i = len; i < 17; i++) {
          buffer[i] = 0;
        }
        fprintf(output,"%06x", num);
        fprintf(output, "%s", ": ");

        for (size_t j=0; j<len; j++) {
           fprintf(output,"%02x", (unsigned char) buffer[j]);
           fprintf(output, "%s", " ");
        }
        if (len < 16) {
            for (size_t k=0; k<16-len; k++) {
                fprintf(output, "%s", "   ");
            }
        }

        fprintf(output, "%s\n", buffer);
        num += 16;
    }
}
```

Вывод такой:
000000: ***e2 80 8b e2 80 8b*** 55 73 65 20 74 68 65 20 66 70 ​​Use the fp

Жирным выделен мусор. Можно ли это как-то обойти без специальных "приседаний"?

Comment: %E2%80%8B is the code for a "ZERO-WIDTH SPACE" character. Если оно всегда есть ,то почему бы не прочитать 6 байт и забыть о них?

Comment: Я не понял что вам не нравится. Если эти байты есть в файле, то почему вы хотите их игнорировать? Если они не нужны, то может стоить поправить файл?

Comment: Непонятно в чем проблема, в конкретном файле этот мусор есть или при чтении любого TXT файла?

Answer (score 0):

Все верно. В начале файла появился "ZERO-WIDTH SPACE". Он появился в результате copy-paste из интернетовского текста.
Убрал в Vim'е и все заработало нормально.
Всем спасибо!